# Read more than 4 bytes from 4 byte register with GDB

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, cpu-registers

I've a question of understanding. For example, a 32 Bit x86 chip has register length of 4 byte. Fine. With gdb, i can specify to read 4 bytes from target register. (`x/4b $edx`).

But if i enter `x/40b` which means "give me 40 bytes from 4 byte register". It confuses me greatly. How is that possible?

Is all after the fourth byte "garbage", or is it from another region in memory / register?

Answer (score 5):

`x` reads memory, not registers.

It gets an *address* from the expression you used (which happens to include a register value), and increments it to read as many bytes from memory as you asked for.

None of those bytes are the register *value*.  The register value only appears in the address column of the `x` output.  (And then only if you happened to use an expression that was a single register, rather than `$eax + $edi`, `$edi + 16`, or `(char*)symbol + 12`)

If you want a register *value*, use `p /x $eax`, or `info reg`, or `layout reg`.